# How to update DataSource of a Combobox using LinqToSQL?

Tags: c#, combobox, linq-to-sql, datasource

I want to update a combobox datasource calling `Combobox.DataSource = DataContext.Orders` when a new **Order** is added. But this call doesn't update the `Combobox` even the entire container and its child controls are recreated. What is the reason for this problem occurs and what is the solution?

My code is below. If a `RadioButton` selection changed, I remove all controls and create a new one according to selection. The `Combobox` update code is working in the Load event.

```
    void UC_AddProductionOrder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbxWorkshops.DataSource = SQLHelper.otdc.Workshops;
        cbxWorkshops.DisplayMember = "WorkshopName";
        cbxWorkshops.ValueMember = "WorkshopID";

        cbxOrders.DataSource = SQLHelper.otdc.Orders;
        cbxOrders.DisplayMember = "OrderID";
        cbxOrders.ValueMember = "OrderID";

        cbxColors.DataSource = SQLHelper.otdc.Colors;
        cbxColors.DisplayMember = "ColorName";
        cbxColors.ValueMember = "ColorID";

        cbxCountries.DataSource = WorldCountries.Countries;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `But this call doesn't update the Combobox` What brought you to that conclusion?

Comment: I clicked the `New Order ID` and added a new `Order` then clicked `New Production Order`. I need to see all `Orders` including the new one in the `Order ID` combobox, but I couldn't. When `New Production Order` radio button is clicked I call that code block to update the `Combobox ` but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?